# Find time of a MAX value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, max

I have a table, Table1, containing the fields TimeStamp and Humidity, which have the values:

TimeStamp
    '2010-09-29 11:05:29.6'
    '2010-09-29 11:05:29.7'
    '2010-09-29 11:05:29.8'
    '2010-09-29 11:05:29.9'
    '2010-09-29 11:05:30.0'

Humidity
       15.291
       17.379
       16.857
       16.335
       15.813

I would like to run a query that returns the value of TimeStamp at the instant that Humidity is at its maximum.  In this example it would return '2010-09-29 11:05:29.7' because that is when Humidity is its highest value, 17.379.  I also want to limit the time range, so it would be something like

```
SELECT _TimeStamp from Table1 
WHERE Humidity = MAX(Humidity) AND 
_TimeStamp >= '2010-09-29 11:05:29.6' AND 
_TimeStamp <= '2010-09-29 11:05:30.0'
```

but this gives an error that aggregates are not permitted in a where clause.  How should this query be written correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 _TimeStamp
 from Table1 
WHERE 
_TimeStamp BETWEEN '2010-09-29 11:05:29.6' AND  '2010-09-29 11:05:30.0'
ORDER BY Humidity DESC
```

Or `SELECT TOP 1  WITH TIES _TimeStamp` if you want to bring back all timestamps matching the max humidity.

For more complicated grouping scenarios you should investigate the ranking functions such as `row_number`

Comment: You may want to consider an additional sort. If the humidity has a max value (I am assuming 100), then you will want to specify what the next order should be. For example, _timestamp descending may be a good choice so you see the most recent max.